# How to prevent a FragmentPagerAdapter from loading the next Fragment in advance?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentpageradapter, android-pageradapter

I am using a `FragmentPagerAdapter` to swipe three Fragments. It's not giving me any errors, but it always loads the next Fragment in advance. How can I stop this behavior?

Here is my `FragmentPagerAdapter`:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private Context _context;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        _context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment f = new Fragment();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            f = ReservationTab.newInstance(_context);
            break;
        case 1: 
            f = GalleryTab.newInstance(_context);
            break;
        case 2:
            f = VideoTab.newInstance(_context);
            break;
        }
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that's the default behavior, to load one previous and next fragments in advance, so that when it comes into view, it doesn't take time to load.

Comment: basically i am playing video in second fragment and it has progress dialog box ... so that its showing the dialog box in first fragment view...

Comment: then you have to use the life cycle methods of the fragments and manage your progress dialog in such a way that the dialog displays only when the second fragment comes into view.

Comment: i am using asyncTask to play video how can i use life cycle method plz give some more suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2 /*count of your fragments in viwePager*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using setOffscreenPageLimit(0) on your ViewPager